# Memory side effects of setvbuf

Tags: c, output-buffering

I'm wondering what sort of side effects there are for using the `setvbuf` function.

An example use case:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ); // Call #1
// Many calls to fprintf(stdout, ...);

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ); // Call #2
// Many calls to fprintf(stdout, ...);

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZ); // Call #3
// More calls to fprintf(stdout, ...);
```

Given that Buffer A is allocated with the calls to `printf` after Call #1, I would want one of two behaviors:

1. Buffer A is freed with calls to `printf` after Call #2
2. Buffer A is reallocated with calls to `printf` after Call #3

What I don't want to happen would be for Buffer A to not be freed or reallocated, giving me a memory leak.

Is the actual behavior one of the two desired behaviors?

Comment: It's your C library's job to handle this when you pass a `NULL` pointer.  Your C library should, upon program exit, deallocate any memory it used for its own internal purposes.  AFAIK it might not reallocate, but it certainly should deallocate memory.

Comment: It's allocated with calls to `printf` after Call #1. I'm sure it will deallocate on program exit. What I'm more interested in is what happens during runtime: whether repeated calls with _IOFBF will cause a memory leak.

Comment: You can only call `setvbuf()` once, before any output occurs on the file stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard specifies (7.19.5.6):

> The setvbuf function may be used only after the stream pointed to by
>   stream has been associated with an open file and before any other
>   operation (other than an unsuccessful call to setvbuf) is performed on
>   the stream.

So repeatedly calling `setvbuf` on the same stream, as you do, is undefined behavior.

You didn't specify what platform you were on, but [glibc's implementation](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libio/iosetvbuf.c;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a) doesn't seem to reallocate the memory.